# Accessing a given file by date on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

I wrote this in PowerShell:
Ideally it should check $myDIRECTORY and get all the files that have been created during $myCreationTime, it works flawlessly, now I want to access the file, so I wrote a For-Each-Object{} to print the file:

```
    Get-ChildItem $myDIRECTORY  | Where-Object {
    $_.CreationTime.Date.ToString() -match $myCreationTime | ForEach-Object{
        Write-Host $_.ToString()
    }
}
```

However I get the boolean Match value, so:

```
False
False
True
False
```

How can I get the True file? $_.BaseName isn't working and it's unsurprisingly, I understand it's a boolean, so I don't even know why I tried it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your foreach loop you get only the result of the match operation.

Try it like that:

```
Get-ChildItem $myDIRECTORY  | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.CreationTime.Date.ToString() -match $myCreationTime) {
        $_.BaseName
    }
}
```

Comment: How could've I been so blind! Thank you so much!